# How to update two tables with MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how do I update two tables using mysql and php?

How would I add the second table to the code?

Here is the code below.

```
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tags SET count='$tag_info_count' WHERE id='$tag_info_id'")
```

Comment: What second table, and how does it relate to the first?

Comment: Try making a little more effort if you want help...

Answer (score 1):

You create a [transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). I forget the transaction syntax for mysqli, but basically

```
try 
{
   mysql_begin_transaction(); //not correct syntax
   mysql_query("UPDATE table1..."); // not correct syntax
   mysql_query("UPDATE table2..."); // not correct syntax
   msyql_commit_transaction() // not correct syntax
}
catch (Exception E)
{
   msyql_rollback_transaction(); // not correct syntax
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check out [Execute Multiple MySQL Queries from One String in PHP](http://www.dev-explorer.com/articles/multiple-mysql-queries).

Otherwise, write separate query statements in your PHP.